# Filter and search using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code using AngularJS for search text.
But can't display rows in the table and search is not working well.
HTML

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search name" ng-modle="searchText.name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search city" ng-modle="searchText.city" />
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="exactMatch" /> Exact match
            <br /> <br />
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:searchText:exactMatch">
                        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.city}}</td>                      
                    </tr>                    
                </tbody>
            </table>       
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[])
                   .controller("myController", function ($scope){
    var employees = [
       {name:"Ben", gender:"Male", salary:55500.00, city:"London"},
       {name:"Thomas", gender:"Male", salary:56000.00, city:"Melbourne"},
       {name:"Lin", gender:"Male", salary:78000.00, city:"Texas"}, 
       {name:"Ben", gender:"Male", salary:85000.00, city:"Sydney"},
       {name:"Ben", gender:"Male", salary:44000.00, city:"Singapore"}
    ];
    $scope.employees = employees;
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thtain/t9ru89Lr/1/)
What are wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please show what results you're getting and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple issues:
1) You've not included ng-app (in the jsfiddle)
2) You've misspelled ng-model in a couple places

Here is your code working on jsbin: 
http://jsbin.com/tahiwocuvu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is spell model correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10785/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search name" ng-model="searchText.name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search city" ng-model="searchText.city" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the `ng-app` tag correctly (missing from your fiddle), either from the jsfiddle options or in your code. In order to make your search working, use the correct spelling of `ng-model`. Also remember to include AngularJS in your fiddle from the JavaScript options. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/divyanshu013/t9ru89Lr/7/) is a working fork of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled the ng-model(ng-modle)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search name" ng-model="searchText.name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search city" ng-model="searchText.city" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misspelled

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search name" ng-model="searchText.name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search city" ng-model="searchText.city" />
```